# can't post on facebook with selenium (python)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, selenium

I was able to post on Facebook some days ago with selenium(python)

I could find post text Box with this below method

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='xhpc_message']")
```

but it seems Facebook has made some changes recently so it's not working anymore. and I am not even able to post any link with **https** or **www**  anymore with

```
    element.send_keys("https://.....");
```

I have tested manually It's working but not with selenium(python)

so any way to work around it, any help

Comment: why would you post on facebook with selenium? what´s the use case for this? you should use the api instead.

Comment: I want to post on facebook some blog's posts when they post it on their blog web, Blog's post link automatically be posted on facebook with the title

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that, thanks. okay well then I will use Facebook Graph API